# Ionic D3.js piechart does not render

Tags: d3.js, ionic-framework, nvd3.js

Having trouble with rendering the piechart using nvd3.js in Ionic 1.0.1
Any Help will be appreciated

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6xko.jpg)

**IONIC PAGE CODE **

```
<ion-view class="layouts-view">
 <!--  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
   -->
     <ion-nav-back-button >
        <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
     </ion-nav-back-button>
  <ion-nav-title>
    <span>Report Charts</span>
  </ion-nav-title>
  <ion-content>


        <div class="item item-divider">
            Pie chart 2 - interactive
        </div>
        <div class="item item-text-wrap" >
             <nvd3 options="vm.options" data="vm.data3" config="config"  ></nvd3>
        </div>

  </ion-content>
```

**- CONTROLLER -**

```
$scope.vm = {};

        $scope.vm.data3 = [
            {
                key: "One",
                y: 5
            },
            {
                key: "Two",
                y: 2
            },
            {
                key: "Three",
                y: 9
            },
            {
                key: "Four",
                y: 7
            },
            {
                key: "Five",
                y: 4
            },
            {
                key: "Six",
                y: 3
            },
            {
                key: "Seven",
                y: 5
            }
        ];

$scope.vm.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'pieChart',
                height: 500,
                x: function(d){return d.key;},
                y: function(d){return d.y;},
                showLabels: true,
                duration: 500,
                labelThreshold: 0.01,
                labelSunbeamLayout: true,
                legend: {
                    margin: {
                        top: 5,
                        right: 35,
                        bottom: 5,
                        left: 0
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

**My system information:**
Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.1 
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.1 
OS: Distributor ID: SUSE LINUX Description: openSUSE Leap 42.1 (x86_64) 
Node Version: v0.12.7

Answer (score 0):

Use [NDV3](https://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/) or check this guide for code to use [D3 with Ionic](https://gonehybrid.com/bring-your-ionic-app-to-life-getting-started-with-d3-js/).

**Edit:** if you still have issues then can you try embedding the chrome web browser using this command `ionic browser add crosswalk`. I think your problem is the on-device browser does not support SVG.

Comment: I've used NVD3 - and from the same tutorial ... the output screen is given above, unable to get it to work.

Comment: Can you try embedding the chrome web browser using this command : `ionic browser add crosswalk` - this should work since I think your problem is the on-device browser does not support SVG.

Comment: been using it with crosswalk.